# How to check if Twitter user is not found API

Tags: php, twitter

Is there a way to detect whether the inserted twitter username by the visitor is not correct?

The only way I found is when receiving the JSON from Twitter I check whether the JSON object contain the message `Sorry, that page does not exist`

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
```

*I'm using PHP and TwitterOAuth by Abraham if it matters.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure the Twitter API will return an HTTP 404 (Not Found) in this case.

eg. This request will return a 404: https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=ThisScreenNameDoesNotExist&include_entities=false

May be useful to glance over the list of HTTP status codes, since a lot of APIs will conform to this standard.
I always find this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) nicely explains them *all*.

So, in your PHP code, you would do something like this (assuming you're using `curl` directly)

```
curl_exec($curlHandle);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curlHandle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 404) {
    echo 'User does not exist';
}
```

For reference, the [Error Codes & Responses page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses) in the Twitter API docs does state that a Twitter Error 34 is equivalent to HTTP 404.

Comment: The code: 34  is 404?

Comment: It's important to understand the differences between the two codes. 34 is a Twitter-specific code. 404 is an HTTP code. But yes, in this case, `34 == 404`.

Comment: Just to point out, the link above starting "https://api.twitter.com/1/" is deprecated (v1.0 API) and is being retired **as of today** (11th June 2013). Calls to that url will never work as expected again.

Comment: @Jimbo, that's correct. Can't believe I forgot about that. Crazy coincidence that the switch is happening today, too!